# How can I buy Mastercoins?

Tags: exchanges, alternatives, omni

What is currently the best way to purchase Mastercoins?

Are there exchanges out yet?

Do I need some special Mastercoin-Address/Wallet?

Comment: Please either provide a comprehensive answer, listing several options preferably with an evaluation of advantages and disadvantages/another explanation for your rating, or refrain from answering.

Comment: this project was rebranded for Omni. This question is now obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to purchase the funds are to go to http://www.buymastercoin.com/ and make  a purchase as described on the site.

Or just go to the google spreadsheet that is used as a sort of an exchange where you can purchase from the MSC holders themselves: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApGPLGUd5ZCzdHFxbnhHQjBDSDVKamY5UHlWdkNMNWc&usp=sharing#gid=0

No need for a special Wallet but it is definitely recommendable to make a new address for the Mastercoins